# How to get request url in upstream server after rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx as a proxy server: client -> nginx (server1:80) -> server (server2:81)
The client requests a json resource (HAL format) from the server in which the server generates the needed URIs inside the JSON+HAL resource.

I'm using `proxy_pass` in nginx config:

```
location /context {
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_redirect off;
    rewrite /context(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://server2:81;
}
```

The problem is that the generated URIs from server2 do not contain the context root `/context`.
Example:
Client request URI -> `http://server1/context/foo/bar`
URI used by server1 (nginx) to request server2 -> `http://server2:81/foo/bar`

The generated URIs in the response JSON is `http://server1/foo/bar/baz` as it should be `http://server1/context/foo/bar/baz`

Is there a way to tell server2 that the GET header is `/context/foo/bar` that server2 generates the correct URI in its response? (it's a .NET server and they are using the `HttpHelper` class to generate the URI).

Comment: I guess, you oversimplified your code. What's exactly in `proxy_pass`?

Comment: This is the actual code (with just a different host name). I also tried with `rewrite` but could not find it.

Comment: Do you really not have `/` after `:81`? Or `rewrite` somewhere? In this code, there is nothing that would strip `/context` part.

Comment: indeed, my bad. Just edited my post.

Comment: `rewrite /(.*) $1 break;` ?

Comment: Well, you rewrited request. How should server2 guess, that it have to prepend `/context` to path? And what for do you rewrite request?

Comment: That will not work because it adds `/context` to the request URI to server2.

Comment: There is no “GET header”. You need to pass full request and configure server2 to handle it properly. Or pass original request in some custom header and use it somehow on server2

Comment: GET header was just a way to say when I sniff the requests, on the GET line. I also thought about adding a custom header or change the server2 context but I was wandering if it was possible do it in another way (with nginx or via default HTTP headers).